# getting the faulty item during continuation

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

I am using task continuation as shown in code below. Problem is that I would like to know which urls are failed. I was hoping there is some way of doing it in contination code where I am checking for t.ISFaulted

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var UIContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    var URLsToProcess = new List<string>
            {
                "http://www.microsoft.com",
                "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
                "http://www.google.com",
                "http://www.apple.com",
                "http://www.ebay.com",
                "http://www.oracle.com",
                "http://www.gmail.com",
                "http://www.amazon.com",
                "http://www.outlook.com",
                "http://www.yahoo.com",
                "http://www.amazon124.com",
                "http://www.msn.com"
                };

       string[] tURLs = null;
       Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
            tURLs = URLsToProcess
                .AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(3)
                .Select(uri => DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(uri)).Result)
                .ToArray();
        });

        task.ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            if ( t.IsFaulted )
                // How to know which URL has failed
        }, UIContext});

}

static Task<string> DownloadStringAsTask(Uri address)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs =
      new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Error != null) 
            tcs.SetException(args.Error);
        else if (args.Cancelled) 
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        else 
            tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
    };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(address);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer. There is something fundamentally wrong with your approach. I just realized your code is very complex than what it should be. Please explain what you're trying to achieve instead of asking what you thought was the solution. I'll try to help.

Comment: i am downloading data from various URLs using TPL. Once download is complete I want to know which urls failed and which url succeed. Please do suggest any suggestions for things you finding wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use [Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package, I'll definitely recommend it. Otherwise start all the tasks, then just use `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll` to wait for them asynchronously.

```
private void DownloadData()
{
    var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    var urLsToProcess = new List<string>
    {
        "http://www.microsoft.com",
        "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
        "http://www.google.com",
        "http://www.apple.com",
        "http://www.ebay.com",
        "http://www.oracle.com",
        "http://www.gmail.com",
        "http://www.amazon.com",
        "http://www.outlook.com",
        "http://www.yahoo.com",
        "http://www.amazon124.com",
        "http://www.msn.com"
        };

    var tasks = urLsToProcess.Select(x => DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(x)))
        .ToArray();

    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, (Task<string>[] tasks1) =>
    {
        foreach (var task in tasks1)
        {
            //task.AsyncState will contain the Uri, add it to the textbox
            if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} : Completed", task.AsyncState));
            }
            else if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} : Faulted", task.AsyncState));
            }
            else if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} : Canceled", task.AsyncState));
            }
            textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }

    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, uiContext);
}

static Task<string> DownloadStringAsTask(Uri address)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs =
      new TaskCompletionSource<string>(address);
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Error != null)
            tcs.SetException(args.Error);
        else if (args.Cancelled)
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        else
            tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
    };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(address);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Note there is one change in `DownloadStringAsTask` method, I call the `TaskCompletionSource` constructor with `URI`, so that you can access it via `AsyncState` property. `textBox1` is just a TextBox control to demonstrate. You could change the code as your needs.

`Task.Status` will tell you whether the Task is canceled or faulted or completed successfully. When task is successfully completed (i.e `task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion`) you can access `task.Result` safely to get the response string.